# Ошибка при публикации записи на стене ВК, VK-SDK

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой...
Делаю публикацию на стену через createWallPost, самую простую, обычный текст, произвольной длины от нескольких символов до довольно большого текста... И блин, публикует через раз, хочет скажет что мол параметр ей не нравится, на следующий раз захочет и опубликует... Я в замешательстве. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Метод публикации записи:

```
api.createWallPost(account.user_id, text, null, null, false, false, false, null, null, new Long(0), new Long(0), null, null);
```

Лог ошибки:

```
One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: invalid message param
```